# How to store --exclude arguments for grep in an environment variable in a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, environment-variables

My goal is to search a file-hierarchy for certain text patterns, excluding certain file-name patterns, and recursively copy just the matching files to a local directory named `confs`. The following script does the job:

```
#!/bin/bash
export FEXCLUDE="{*edit,*debug,*orig,*BAK,*bak,*fcs,*NOPE,*tomcat,*full.xml,*-ha.xml}";
export SRCDIR=/opt/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone;

confshow() {
  for ii in `grep -rlZ \
  --exclude={*edit,*debug,*orig,*BAK,*bak,*fcs,*NOPE,*tomcat,*full.xml,*-ha.xml} \
  --exclude-dir={log,tmp,i2b2.war,*.log,*_history,*.old} "<datasource\|username\|password\|user-name" \
  $SRCDIR/*  | xargs -0 ls {}` ; 
    do cp --parents $ii confs; 
  done;
}
```

However, the exclusion patterns are likely to need frequent updates and may need to be shared with other functions, so I prefer to have them all in a variables declared at the beginning of the script. When I do the following, files that should be excluded get copied to the `confs` directory:

```
#!/bin/bash
export FEXCLUDE="{*edit,*debug,*orig,*BAK,*bak,*fcs,*NOPE,*tomcat,*full.xml,*-ha.xml}";
export SRCDIR=/opt/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone;

confshow() {
  for ii in `grep -rlZ \
  --exclude=$FEXCLUDE \
  --exclude-dir={log,tmp,i2b2.war,*.log,*_history,*.old} "<datasource\|username\|password\|user-name" \
  $SRCDIR/*  | xargs -0 ls {}` ; 
    do cp --parents $ii confs; 
  done;
}
```

Any idea how to obtain the desired behavior? Or how to see what `grep` sees when it gets passed the `$FEXCLUDE` argument (`echo` doesn't show anything wrong)?

Thanks.

Comment: strange indeed. Since the expression doesn't need quotes, I wonder why you define FEXCLUDE variable with quotes. Should work without. Worth a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this will raise frowns but this can be solved by using `eval` and it might not come with usual risks as we're using pattern in `--exclude=` argument.

```
#!/bin/bash

fexclude='{*edit,*debug,*orig,*BAK,*bak,*fcs,*NOPE,*tomcat,*full.xml,*-ha.xml}'
dexclude='{log,tmp,i2b2.war,*.log,*_history,*.old}'
srcdir=/opt/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone

confshow() {
  eval grep -rlZ \
    --exclude="$fexclude" \
    --exclude-dir="$dexclude" \
    "<datasource\|username\|password\|user-name" \
    $srcdir/* | xargs -0 -I {} cp --parents '{}' confs
  done
}
```

Comment: I learned a lot from both answers, and am grateful to you both. This answer ended up being the one that worked.

Answer (score 3):

Brace expansion is nice for interactive use, but if you are writing a script, just use your editor to quickly copy the necessary `--exclude` options and store them in an array. Parameter expansions do not undergo brace expansion, as you may have noticed.

```
#!/bin/bash
# You didn't need to export these anyway, since only your script uses them
FEXCLUDE=( --exclude '*edit'
           --exclude '*debug'
           # etc
)
DEXCLUDE=( --exclude-dir log
           --exclude-dir tmp
           # etc
)
SRCDIR=/opt/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone

confshow() {
while IFS= read -d'' -r ii; do
    cp --parents "$ii" confs
done < <( grep -rlZ "${FEXCLUDE[@]}" "${DEXCLUDE[@]}" "<datasource\|username\|password\|user-name" $SRCDIR/* )
```

Also, using `ls` defeats the purpose of using null-delimited output from `grep` in the first place.

Comment: This sources without error, but nothing gets copied over now.

Comment: I forgot to copy the actual search patterns.

Comment: @chepner: Is there any reason to use uppercase variable names in this case?

Comment: @l'L'l No; I just followed the original code. Lowercase would be better, since uppercase is technically reserved by shell.

Comment: @chepner: That's what i was getting at, as I've seen it mentioned quite a bit on here not to use uppercase names unless necessary (exports, etc.). It makes sense, although it does somewhat contradict what is mentioned here: http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_02.html. It more or less states you can use either, so I'm not sure what to actually believe.

Comment: Officially, the POSIX specification reserves all names that consist solely of all capital letters. That doesn't mean it actually *uses* all of them, but it does promise that any variable you might be using that contains at least one non-uppercase letter won't suddenly be chosen for use by the operating system.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Added in search term, but now getting errors that look like it's trying to split every file-path by hyphens. Is the intent of `IFS=` to set the IFS to null?